# Python / Pandas - 'column' not in index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and when I `print(delivery.columns)` I get the following:

```
Index(['Complemento_endereço', 'cnpj', 'Data_fundação', 'Número',
   'Razão_social', 'CEP', 'situacao_cadastral', 'situacao_especial', 'Rua',
   'Nome_Fantasia', 'last_revenue_normalized', 'last_revenue_year',
   'Telefone', 'email', 'Capital_Social', 'Cidade', 'Estado',
   'Razão_social', 'name_bairro', 'Natureza_Jurídica', 'CNAE', '#CNAE',
   'CNAEs_secundários', 'Pessoas', 'percent'],
  dtype='object')
```

Well, we can clearly see that there is a column 'Rua'.

Also, if I `print(delivery.Rua)` I get a full dataframe:

```
82671                         R JUDITE MELO DOS SANTOS
817797                                R DOS GUAJAJARAS
180081           AV MARCOS PENTEADO DE ULHOA RODRIGUES
149373                                 AL MARIA TEREZA
455511                               AV RANGEL PESTANA
...
```

Even if I write  `if 'Rua' in delivery.columns: print('here I am')` it does print the 'here I am'. So 'Rua' is in fact there.

Well, in the immediate line after I have this code:

```
delivery=delivery.set_index('cnpj')[['Razão_social','Nome_Fantasia','Data_fundação','CEP','Estado','Cidade','Bairro','Rua','Número','Complemento_endereço',
                                                 'Telefone','email','Capital_Social', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Natureza_Jurídica','Pessoas' ]]
```

And voilá, I get this weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/file.py", line 45, in <module>
   'Telefone', 'email', 'Capital_Social', 'Cidade', 'Estado',
   'Razão_social', 'name_bairro', 'Natureza_Jurídica', 'CNAE', '#CNAE',
'Telefone','email','Capital_Social', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Natureza_Jurídica','Pessoas' ]]
   'CNAEs_secundários', 'Pessoas', 'percent'],
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1991, in __getitem__
  dtype='object')
return self._getitem_array(key)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2035, in _getitem_array
indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1214, in _convert_to_indexer
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['Rua'] not in index"
```

Can someone help? I'm starting to think I'm crazy and 'Rua' is an illusion of my troubled mind.

**EDIT**

I'm using this code right before the error line:

```
delivery=pd.DataFrame()

for i in selection.index:
    sample=groups.get_group(selection['#CNAE'].loc[i]).sample(selection['samples'].loc[i])
    delivery=pd.concat((delivery,sample)).sort_values('Capital_Social',ascending=False)


print(delivery.columns)
print(delivery.Rua)
print(delivery.set_index('cnpj').columns)

delivery=delivery.set_index('cnpj')[['Razão_social','Nome_Fantasia','Data_fundação','CEP','Estado','Cidade','Bairro','Rua','Número','Complemento_endereço',
                                 'Telefone','email','Capital_Social', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Natureza_Jurídica','Pessoas' ]]
```

**EDIT 2**

New weird stuff:
I gave up and deleted 'Rua' from that last piece of code, wishing that it would work. For my surprise, I had the same problem but now with the column 'Número'.

```
delivery=delivery.set_index('cnpj')[['Razão_social','Nome_Fantasia','Data_fundação','CEP','Estado','Cidade','Bairro','Número','Complemento_endereço',
                                                 'Telefone','email','Capital_Social', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Natureza_Jurídica' ]]

KeyError: "['Número'] not in index"
```

**EDIT 3**

And then I gave up on 'Número' and took it out. Then the same problem happened with 'Complemento_endereço'. Then I deleted 'Complemento_endereço'. And it happend to 'Telefone' and so on.

Comment: Try `print(delivery.set_index('cnpj').columns)`

Comment: just tried it and 'Rua' is right there: Index(['Complemento_endereço', 'Data_fundação', 'Número', 'Razão_social',
       'CEP', 'situacao_cadastral', 'situacao_especial', 'Rua',
       'Nome_Fantasia', 'last_revenue_normalized', 'last_revenue_year',
       'Telefone', 'email', 'Capital_Social', 'Cidade', 'Estado',
       'Razão_social', 'name_bairro', 'Natureza_Jurídica', 'CNAE', '#CNAE',
       'CNAEs_secundários', 'Pessoas', 'percent'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Can you show the most relevant lines to this code? Maybe +-5 lines to the line throwing the error.

Comment: Sure. There it is @COLDSPEED

Comment: Possibly a bug -- try upgrading your version: `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: It's possible, maybe even likely, that `Rua` in the DataFrame is a different Unicode spelling.  Try copy-pasting the name from the `columns` output into your code.  Try using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before it crashes and play with the data interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JohnZwinck but I tried copy-pasting the 'Rua' from the output into the code but the problem persists... also I tried upgrading pandas as COLDSPEED suggested, but the problem didn't seem to disappear. I think I will separate it from the dataframe and merge it back again.

Comment: Separating didn't work out. The problem started happening with 'Número'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the problem was in "Bairro" not in "Rua" but pandas 0.18 had a bug that displayed the item just before it.
The strange thing is that all the stars conspired against. I tried upgrading Pandas before and it upgraded me to version 0.18 and not to the 0.20 (that had this fix). Now I forced the 0.20 and it worked.